# stuck with reductions of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use reduction of order (or the formula) to find a second solution:

$y''+16y=0$ given $y_1=cos4x$

The formula they refer to is $y_2=\int\frac{e^{-\int P(x)dx}}{y_1^2}dx$
So $y_2=cos4x \int \frac{e^{-\int 16 dx}}{(cos4x)^2}dx$ which results in an integral that is impossible/very difficult to solve (bonus points for those who solve it*). Where did I go wrong?

*according to Maple it's [image: (1/2*I)*exp(-16*x)/((exp((4*I)*x))^2+1)+int((8*I)*exp(-16*x)/((exp((4*I)*x))^2+1), x)]

Comment: @Amzoti you don't even know which answers I upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After substituting $y_2(x) = v(x) y_1(x)$, we arrive at:

$$\cos (4 x) v''(x)-8 \sin (4 x) v'(x) = 0$$

Make the substitution $w = v' \implies w' = v''$, yielding:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{w}~dw = \int 8 \tan x ~ dx$$

This yields:

$$w(x) = c_1 \sec^2 4x$$

We now have:

$$v' = w = c_1 \sec^2 4x \implies v(x) = c_1 \tan 4x + c_2$$

Lastly,

$$y_2(x) = v(x) y_1(x) = (c_1 \tan 4x + c_2) \cos 4 x = c_1 \cos 4 x + c_2 \sin 4x$$

**Update**

Using your approach, $P(x) = 0$ and this will give the same result I show above. This means we have:

$$\displaystyle y_2(x) = \cos 4x \int \dfrac{e^{0 dx}}{\cos^2 4x}dx = \cos 4x \left(\dfrac{1}{4} \tan 4 x + c \right) = c_1 \cos 4x + c_2 \sin 4 x$$